# Frequency difference measurements

Tags: digital-communications, frequency-domain

I am trying to find the frequency difference ($\Delta f= f_1 - f_2$) between two complex sinusoidal signals using Matlab. The two signals are:
$$r_1 (t)= A~ e^{j 2 \pi f_1 t}= A \cos(2 \pi f_1 t)+j A\sin(2 \pi f_1 t)$$
$$r_2 (t)= A~ e^{j 2 \pi f_2 t}= A \cos(2 \pi f_2 t)+j A\sin(2 \pi f_2 t)$$
where $f_1=150\, \text{KHz}$ and $f_2=400\, \text{KHz}$

In my Matlab code, I considered the signals are sampled at $F_s=900 \, \text{KHz}$ then

```
    A=1;
    j=sqrt(-1);
    f_1=150e3;
    f_2=400e3;
    Fs=900e3;    
    n=0:1/Fs:1-1/Fs;
    r1s= A*cos(2*pi*f_1*n)+1j*A*sin(2*pi*f_1*n);
    r2s= A*cos(2*pi*f_2*n)+1j*A*sin(2*pi*f_2*n);
```

Then, to find $\Delta f$, I multiplied both signals as follows:

```
     z= r1s.*conj(r2s);
     Fz=fft(z);
     subplot(2,1,1)
     plot(real(Fz));
     subplot(2,1,2)
     plot(imag(Fz));
```

Then, I applied $\text{FFT}$ and plotted the real and imaginary part of the multiplication. But I could not find the pulse at $f_1 - f_2$. The pulse was at high frequency.

Also, I multiplied the two signals as

```
     z2= r1s.*r2s;
     Fz2=fft(z2);
     subplot(2,1,1)
     plot(real(Fz2));
     subplot(2,1,2)
     plot(imag(Fz2));
```

and applied $\text{FFT}$. The pulse was at $f_1 + f_2$, which means that what I am doing makes sense.

My question is why could I not get the frequency difference when I applied the multiplication with complex conjugate?

Comment: Please post code that actually runs. I've edited it adding multiply operators, but you still need to define `A`, `f_1`, `f_2` and `Fs`.
Pasted code should run "as-is"

Comment: I have a feeling I know what's going on here... Could you post the code that you are using for the fft?

Comment: @Jdip , I already defined defined the variables. The code does not have any problem and it works perfectly. I just included part of it for simplicity.

@djg135, I used the matlab fft function  `fft(z)` to do the FFT.

Comment: You get a peak at $f_1-f_2 = -250 kHz$ which wraps around to 650 kHz . If you want $f_2-f_1$ you need to use `z= r2s.*conj(r1s);`

Comment: @Hilmar 
Thank you sir!! It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you're *multiplying*
$$r_1(t) \times r_2(t) = e^{j\omega_1 t}e^{j\omega_2 t}$$ so in the frequency domain, you're *convolving*:
$$R_1(\omega) \,\circledast \,R_2(\omega) = 2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_1)\,\circledast\,2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_2)$$ which gives you a value at $\omega_1 + \omega_2$. In terms of frequency, that's $150 + 400 = 550\, \text{kHz}$

---

The Fourier transform of the conjugate is the conjugate of the *frequency reversed* Fourier Transform:
$$r_2(t) \xrightarrow{} R_2(\omega)\\
r_2^{*}(t) \xrightarrow{} R_2^{*}(-\omega)$$
Note that because the Fourier Transform of a complex exponential is real, $R_2(\omega)$ is real, so $$R_2^{*}(-\omega) = R_2(-\omega) = 2\pi\delta((2\pi - \omega) - \omega_2)$$

The point is that $R_2$ is *reversed*, **which in the frequency domain gives you a value at** $\omega = 2\pi - \omega_2$.

---

With that in mind, in the second case you're *multiplying*
$$r_1(t) \times r_2^{*}(t) = e^{j\omega_1 t}e^{-j\omega_2 t}$$ so in the frequency domain, you're *convolving*:
$$R_1(\omega) \,\circledast \,R_2(-\omega) = 2\pi\delta(\omega-\omega_1)\,\circledast\,2\pi\delta((2\pi-\omega)-\omega_2)$$ which gives you a value in the spectrum at $\omega = \omega_1 + 2\pi - \omega_2$.

In terms of frequency, that's $150 + 900 - 400 = 650\, \text{kHz}$

Comment: Yes, @Jdip. I got a pulse at $650kHz$ as you described in the last section. 
 To get $f_1 − f_2$ ,  I did multiply `r2s.*conj(r1s)` as @Hilmar suggested.

Comment: @wesamamiri 
That's to get $f_2 - f_1$ actually, but yes, in that case that's $\omega_2 + 2\pi - \omega_1 = 400 + 900 - 150 = 1150 \, \text{Hz}$, which wraps around to $250 \, \text{Hz}$
Glad I could help, hopefully you understand better why what's happening is happening. Please accept the answer if you're satisfied so others know it's been resolved ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
I do care about the absolute value of the frequency difference (drift). So, $f_1 - f_2$ will be the same as $f_2 - f_1$ for my case. 
I did accept your answer.